# Integrating SOAP and VXML

Tags: web-services, jsp, soap, axis

I am writing an interface for our `VXML` application that will allow access to a `SOAP` service.
Because of the difficulties inherent in trying to use javascript to make `SOAP` calls and the limitations of `VXML`, as in making external resource calls are pretty much limited to `HTTP` requests, `GET` and `POST`.

I designed a java servlet that would act as a service provider to the `VXML` application.  It can call this servlet with arguments indicating the web service type, the method name to invoke and the arguments to pass to it.  The servlet then makes the appropriate web service call and returns the response in a standardized `VXML` document response.

The issue is I severely underestimated how difficult `SOAP` really is.  I thought I could just simply construct the soap call and do it in java, however its looking to me like this is something a little more involved, requiring things like `Apache Axis2`.

I read somewhere that listeners for `Axis` could be `HTTP servlets`, which sounds a lot like what I am doing already.
Am I re-inventing the wheel here?
Is there any suggestion out there for me as to how to do this better?
I am pretty invested in the way I'm doing it now and so would be very receptive to an easy way to accomplish the `SOAP` call and process the response from a `jsp servlet`.

**EDIT** - After taking the advice here I've delved a little further into `Axis`.
As it turns out, `Axis2` is Apache's third generation of `Apache SOAP`.  Whats unfortunate about this is that after extensive searching I cannot find a single solitary place where the original `Apache SOAP` implementation can be downloaded.
I might not care if:

A) `Axis` would allow me to integrate a few `jars` and `jsps` rolled
    into a standalone `WAR` app

B) everything .. i mean everything up to this point has been done using
    examples from `ApacheSOAP` (the book i was using, the code I've
    written thus far .. everything).

So I google some more thinking .. hey, there has to be some kind of stand alone library for `Java` that would just simply allow me to make a single solitary simple `SOAP` call and parse the results.
But no, no such luck!
Apparently if you want to use `Java` and `SOAP` you have either the gigantic incomprehensibly thick and complicated axis or .. you roll your own soap implementation from the ground up.  I am so burned on this.  I don't get why soap is so wonderful given the last 7 13 hour days I've spent just trying to get a simple `hello world` request to work from `JSP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A library like `Axis` is definitely the solution, you do not want to attempt to build/parse `SOAP` messages on your own.

Look at using [`wsdl2java`](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL) ([another link](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/ant/axis-wsdl2java.html), and [another](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/tools/1_0/CodegenToolReference.html)) to create client proxies for which you can invoke the `web services`. This will generate a bunch of `Java` code which you can call into from your code, and then `Axis` will handle packaging your arguments into `XML` messages, sending it across the wire to the server, de-serializing the response, etc.

Comment: Thank you.  I recently cleared up a few misconceptions I had with this and with talking with others.  SOAP is not as bloated as I thought, even though I still think it is ... bloated.  ;0)